# authorize access to volume does not return allowed host

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

this API is supposed to return an array of SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Allowed_Host, according to the [document](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/allowAccessFromHostList).

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/17336531/allowAccessFromHostList.json

{"parameters":[[{"id":25868261,"objectType":"SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest"}]]}

But actually it returns 200 with empty response body: [{}]

Anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

yep, it is an issue and it was already reported a few months ago, but currently there is no ETA for the fix :(.